# PowerShell - get last accessed (modified) date of multiple files

Tags: powershell

Here is the code I am using:

```
$directory = Read-Host "Directory?"
$outPutFile = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")+"\test.csv"
Get-ChildItem -path $directory -Recurse  | where { $_.lastaccesstime -ge [datetime]$startDate -and $_.lastaccesstime -lt [datetime]$endDate} | select fullname | Export-CSV -Path $outPutFile
```

The error I am receiving:

```
Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".
```

My question is why is this value null? Am I using the wrong command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining `$startDate` or `$endDate`. The following will work:

```
$startDate =  (get-date).addDays(-5)
$endDate =  (get-date).addDays(-3) 
$directory = Read-Host "Directory?"
$outPutFile = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")+"\test.csv"
Get-ChildItem -path $directory -Recurse  | where { $_.LastAccessTime -ge [datetime]$startDate -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt [datetime]$endDate} | select FullName | Export-CSV -Path $outPutFile
```

Comment: Other than the $outPutFile put in there twice it works great. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - amended the answer.